# What does here "grab a cable" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> So just a quick word about color coding, I will use certain colors for
> certain purposes during this series of videos so it will be easier to
> follow.
>
> Now, don't pay too much attention at the moment to what clocks are or
> modulation, we will go through everything soon enough but, for
> example, I will use red cables when dealing with audio, blue for
> clocks gates and triggers, and so on.
>
> To choose a color, basically, we just have to grab a cable again and
> again until we get the color we want.
>
> This might change in future versions of VCV, but the idea is still the same, just having certain colors for certain purposes so it's easier to follow and see what goes where.

What does "grab a cable" mean in this context?

Comment: There is no secret sub-text. These words use the standard dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context it means the same thing as "*to pick*" or "*to choose randomly*".

In a more general sense, "to grab" generally implies taking it with your full hand, as you would for a stick or a metal pipe/bar, but here it is just a familiar way to state "take something from what is available next to you".